# Nautilus Advanced Features

Tags: nautilus

I'm using nautilus as file manager for local and remote ftp files.

I'm interested in some advanced features and how they can be achieved.

- Default extra pane.
- Synchronised browsing between two panes.
- Copy file from one pane to another with keyboard shortcut.
- Ignore .svn files while copying entire folders.

Answer (score 4):

I use http://www.nautilus-actions.org/ to add custom context menu options for special file types (i.e. to render `rST` files)

**Update**: I just realized that you don't want a list of all advanced features but the specific ones you listed. Maybe the answer is helpful anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Default extra pane.

Not possible with builtin options. Some people use xdotool to send the F3 key to nautilus windows.

> Copy file from one pane to another with keyboard shortcut.

Assign a keyboard shortcut to the "Edit -> Copy to..." menu item.

Comment: Thanks. How can I assign keyboart shortcuts, I don't see that in preferences?

Comment: I think this setting disappeared some versions ago from the system settings, but is still available via gconf. Turn on the toggle key `/desktop/gnome/interface/can_change_accels`. Then, hover with your mouse over the menu item, and press the desired key. You might want to toggle the gconf key off again once you're done. This not only works in Nautilus, but in many other GTK+ applications as well.

Comment: Does not work for me. I set can_change_accels option, but after hover item and press key, nothing happends, and shortcut does not work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It doesn't work for every menu (in particularly not for right-click context menus), but it should definitively work with a fairly recent Nautilus (let's say 2.32.0 onwards) and its main menu bar "Edit/Copy to.../Other pane" item.